# xauth list fails

Tags: 18.04, ssh, login, xserver

I have an issue with `xauth list`.
When i run the command `xauth list` from the account `student` I get this error `xauth:  timeout in locking authority file /home/luigi/.Xauthority`. As you can see the command uses the home directory of `luigi` and not the .Xauthority from `/home student`. One test that I did is to remove the `.Xauthority` and login via SSH the student account. however, i get always the same error

how can be possible? any suggestion

Comment: What are the ownership and permissions of `/home/luigi/.Xauthority`? Have you run graphics programs (that use `.Xauthority`) as `root`? It's a well-known Bad Idea.

Comment: Hi, the problem is not he user luigi but  all other users. I can run GUI application via SSH but this is not true for other users